# How to make a random number math quiz with 10 questions in C++?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make a random number math quiz with 10 questions, but my loop isn't stopping with just the first question.

I'm trying to make the loop one question at a time and as the user answers question1, it will go to question2 and so on until all 10 questions are answered, and every correct answer will be added to the score 1 point per question. Can any one help me with this?

edit:1
ok i changed the code as you said like this right?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Player = 0;
    int question = 1;
    int nquestion = 10;
    int choice = 0;

    int qanswere1 = 0;
    int panswere1 = 0;

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int score = 0;

    cout << "Lets Start" <<endl;
    cout << "[1] Addition" <<endl;
    cout << "[3] End" <<endl;
    cout << "Choose: ";
    cin >>choice;

    if(choice == 1){
        choice = 0;

        cout << "Level" <<endl;
        cout << "[1] Easy (1 - 10)" <<endl;
        cout << "Choose: ";
        cin >> choice;

        while(choice == 1){
            for(question = 1; question <= nquestion; question = question + 1 ){
                num1 = rand()%10 +1;
                num2 = rand()%10 +1;
                cout<<num1<<"+"<<num2<<endl;
                qanswere1 = num1 + num2;
                cin>>panswere1;
            }}
        if(panswere1 == qanswere1){
            score = score + 1;
        }
        else{
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

even with this code it still goes beyond 10 questions what am i doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the loop stop to take input for a single question first,and then proceed to further question(s), try taking the input for the variable `panswere1` inside the loop, like this:

```
 for( question = 1; question <= nquestion; question = question + 1 ){
    num1 = rand()%20 +1;
    num2 = rand()%20 +1;
    coutnum1"+"num2endl;
    qanswere1 = num1 + num2;
    cin>>panswere1;
}
```

Note 1: Judging on what the first for loop is doing, it can very well be achieved by

```
while(choice == 1){..
```

without compromising the readability of your code.

Cheers!

**Edit 1:**
To make the code stop at 10 questions, you will have to replace the outer loop

```
for ( choice ==1; choice==1; choice==1){..
```

with a simple if condition:

```
if( choice == 1){..
```

The problem with the for-loop is that it will run infinite number of times, since you have not added any mechanism to limit the number of times it will execute. If you have to limit the number of questions to 10, I would recommend replacing the loop with this if-statement.

**Edit 2:**
You will have to replace the inner while-loop with an if-condition too:
replace

```
while(choice == 1){..
```

with

```
if(choice == 1){..
```

Comment: thx that works! but how can i limit it to 10 it goes beyond 10 now sorry if im not uderstanding it

Comment: @genesia The loop will run for `10` times, assuming that you have assigned 10 to your variable `nquestion` .

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, if it could solve your queries :)

Comment: yep nquestion is still the same even got to 20 questions and it isn't stoping

Comment: Have a loot at `Edit 1` section in the answer :)

Comment: i edited the code like you said but still going please look at the edited code above. what am i doing wrong!?

Comment: Have a look at Edit 2 :) I hope that will solve all your problems :)

Comment: `question = question + 1` could be written as `++question`